how to iterate efficiently through files in order to concatenate them to one dataframe
The data is the physionet 2019 data. It consists of about 40 000 patient records. One file stands for one patient and i want all data in one dataframe.
I have read that when I want to concatenate multiple data samples, I shouldn't append a pandas DataFrame while I'm in the for loop. Instead I should concatenate the data as a list and convert the list in the end to a DataFrame. The first few iteration i was doing 100 iterations per second. But as I go along I only could do like 5 iterations per second.
Can I make my code more efficient? Should I use normal python lists instead of numpy arrays?
pat stands for patient.
for directory in tqdm(os.listdir(dir_path)):
    for file in tqdm(os.listdir(dir_path + '/'+ directory)):
        pat_path = dir_path + '/'+ directory + '/'+ file
        new_pat = pd.read_csv(pat_path,sep='|')
        new_pat['PatID'] = file[1:-4]
        new_pat = new_pat.to_numpy()
        physionet_2019 = np.append(physionet_2019, new_pat, axis=0)


physionet_2019 = pd.DataFrame(physionet_2019, columns= column_names)


You don't append the data to a Python list but to a numpy array which isn't better than appending to a pandas dataframe.

I suppose your target files are the training sets A and B. For the following  I'm assuming that you have a folder data/training/ with 2 subfolders training_setA and training_setB which contain the patient files (roughly 20,000 per set). (You probably have to adjust the code to your specific settings.)
It seems to me like you are trying to do:
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd

path = Path("data/training/")

df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(file, sep="|").assign(PatID=file.name[1:-4])
     for file in tqdm(list(path.rglob("*.psv")))],
    ignore_index=True
)

This works but is rather slow, mostly due to many calls to pd.read_csv
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 40336/40336 [01:10<00:00, 575.41it/s]

(plus the pd.concat time).
I suggest you build a file data.psv that contains all data first, and then read it with Pandas in one go. For example (same imports):
path = Path("data/training/")

with open("data/data.psv", "w") as fout:
    first_file = True
    for file in tqdm(list(path.rglob("*.psv"))):
        patient = file.name[1:-4]
        with open(file, "r") as fin:
            if first_file:  # Read header & write extended header to output file
                cols = next(fin).rstrip()
                fout.write(f"{cols}|PatID\n")
                first_file = False
            else:  # Skip header
                next(fin)
            fout.writelines(f"{line.rstrip()}|{patient}\n" for line in fin)

df = pd.read_csv("data/data.psv", sep="|")

Result:
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 40336/40336 [00:03<00:00, 10719.83it/s]

Both methods result in a dataframe df that looks like:
            HR  O2Sat  Temp    SBP    MAP  ...  Unit2  HospAdmTime  ICULOS  SepsisLabel   PatID
0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN        -0.03       1            0       1
1         97.0   95.0   NaN   98.0  75.33  ...    NaN        -0.03       2            0       1
2         89.0   99.0   NaN  122.0  86.00  ...    NaN        -0.03       3            0       1
3         90.0   95.0   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN        -0.03       4            0       1
4        103.0   88.5   NaN  122.0  91.33  ...    NaN        -0.03       5            0       1
...        ...    ...   ...    ...    ...  ...    ...          ...     ...          ...     ...
1552205   80.0   96.0   NaN  115.0  87.00  ...    NaN         0.00      31            0  120000
1552206   74.0   97.0   NaN  114.0  83.00  ...    NaN         0.00      32            0  120000
1552207   78.0   98.0   NaN  110.0  83.00  ...    NaN         0.00      33            0  120000
1552208   82.0   99.0  36.6  124.0  91.00  ...    NaN         0.00      34            0  120000
1552209   80.0   97.0   NaN  121.0  97.00  ...    NaN         0.00      35            0  120000

